fontweight and image problem with flutter web
I am using flutter web with firebase hosting. Everything is working fine with some exception:
When I build with: flutter build web --release --web-renderer html the fontWeight is ignored and the images coming from firebase storage are properly loaded.
But if I build with flutter build web --release which is the same as flutter build web --release --web-renderer canvaskit the fontWeight is respected but the images are not loaded with the following exception:
error loading image: ImageCodecException: Failed to load network image.

How can I get the fontweight and the images to work properly at the same time?
Thanks
firebase.json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/web",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "europe-west1"
    }
  }
}

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  
    <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta name="description" content="The admin project for my app">

    <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="my app">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

    <title>My app</title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
<script src="flutter_bootstrap.js" async></script>
</body>

